# How do I obtain the rows that contain a specific minimum value?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with 3 rows and 3 columns. For all the rows with the same name, I want to retrieve the one that has the minimum value in the position column. in this example here. The result should be (apple, red, 3) and (melon, big, null).

null value in the 'position' column means that fruit is not in the list.

```
name     category    position
apple     fruit        5
apple      red         3
melon      big       null
```

Comment: And what does a `null` position mean?

Comment: It means that name does not have a position in the category.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `null` makes this tricky.  I'm not sure if it should be considered "high" or "low".  Let me assume "low":

```
select t.*
from t
where coalesce(t.position, -1) = (select min(coalesce(t2.position, -1))
                                  from t t2
                                  where t2.name = t.name
                                 );
```

Comment: How about multiple rows having the same position?

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto . . . That is an appropriate question for the OP.  The phrasing of the question suggests that the "min" position is unique.

Comment: Did you try this query? Because the result is wrong.

Comment: @CrazySabbath It was a typo and he had updated his answer. This query works fine. +1 from my side.

Comment: @Jibin Balachandran you are right, it gives correct result now.

Comment: Hi, guys. I already improved my question. Can you update your vote?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
    f.* 
FROM
(
    SELECT
        name, 
        MIN(IFNULL(position,0)) as min_position 
    FROM 
        fruits 
    GROUP BY 
        name
) tmp
LEFT JOIN 
    fruits f ON 
    f.name = tmp.name AND 
    IFNULL(f.position,0) = min_position
-- GROUP BY name 
-- optional if multiple (name, position) are possible for example
-- [apple,fruit,5], [apple,red,5]
```